# How to set 4 buttons that will take over all the free space?

Tags: wpf

I have some space that i need to add 4 button on it ( each of then appear next to the other ).

I want to be able to set all those button in some way that they will take over all the free space - and all of them will be on same size.

I know that i can use grid and define the grid column and put each of them on different column.

But is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, with a UniformGrid.

Comment: Thanks !!! problem solve :)